How to include GNU Radio header files in custom C++ OOTs
I am writing a C++ OOT module. The module needs the following header file:
#include <gnuradio/digital/constellation.h>
Therefore, I added this line to the following file:
(directory where OOT files are)/include/gnuradio//(blockname.h).
In my case, this is:
(XYZ directory)/gr-QPSK_Modules_Decision_Directed_PLL/include/gnuradio/QPSK_Modules_Decision_Directed_PLL/Decision_Directed_PLL.h
After this, my previous error (regarding the missing header file) goes away, but I run into a new error about a missing header in the following file:
(XYZ directory)/gr-QPSK_Modules_Decision_Directed_PLL/python/QPSK_Modules_Decision_Directed_PLL/bindings/Decision_Directed_PLL_python.cc
at the line:
#include <QPSK_Modules_Decision_Directed_PLL/Decision_Directed_PLL.h>
Note: This is the file I had manually edited in the previous step.
This makes me suspect that manually editing the previous file was probably not the right way to include the header file. I am probably missing something obvious, but I am new to all this, and would appreciate any help. I can't seem to find any example in GNU Radio documentation or wiki page either which shows how to add header files. I had used gr_modtool to create the structure for the C++ OOT module. Any help would be appreciated, as I have no idea how to get past this.
I have tried to replace this line:
#include <QPSK_Modules_Decision_Directed_PLL/Decision_Directed_PLL.h>
with the absolute path of where this file actually is, but this results in linking errors when I attempt to use my block in GRC.
I am using following version of GNU Radio Companion:
3.10.11.0 (Python 3.8.19)

I managed to resolve this issue by running the following command after modifying the header file:
gr_modtool bind [blockname] 

This regenerates the bindings, which seemed to resolve my issue. Hope this helps anyone else who might be having similar problems.
